# "cultivate" means making a lot of effort

Tags: meaning, sentence

I have found out in Cambridge dictionary that, cultivate means making a lot of effort. But I cannot find any nice example for that. Could anyone please provide me an example?

Here is my attempt at using the word with this meaning: "I've been cultivating to increase my knowledge for several years." Is it wrong?

Comment: The meaning is directly derived from the agricultural sense.  If you "cultivate" something you tend to it, fertilize it, use a hoe to loosen the soil around it, etc.  Farmer-like efforts.  "Cultivate friendship" and "cultivate relationship" are probably the most common uses.

Comment: "I've been cultivating to increase my knowledge for several years" is it wrong? @HotLicks

Comment: Generally speaking, you would be cultivating *something*.  Saying "cultivating to" leaves the listener wondering if you were literally using a hoe to increase your knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to **cultivate**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/45724?redirectedFrom=cultivate#eid)

> To try to win the friendship or favour of (a person), now esp. with
>   implications of flattery.
>
> To try to win the friendship or favour of (a person), now esp. with
>   implications of flattery.
>
> To adopt or affect (a mode of behaviour or appearance); to establish
>   or project (a reputation or image).
>
> To take up or develop (an activity, habit, interest, etc.), esp. for
>   the purpose of self-improvement.

As to your question sentences, with modifications:

> "I am spending much effort **cultivating** my dream of X."

and

> "For several years, I've been **cultivating** X to increase my knowledge"

Answer (score 2):

"I've been cultivating my friendship with the managing director for several years"

which means the speaker has spent a significant amount of time/effort on building a friendship with the person in question.  It implies a deliberate effort, rather than the friendship growing naturally, and so one could assume that the speaker has an [*ulterior motive*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ulterior_motive), besides the normal reasons one would be friends with someone, such as a hoped-for promotion or some other business gain.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to use this verb to saying I make a lot of effort to reach my dreams?

Comment: I don't think so.  "Cultivate" is ultimately a **gardening metaphor** - think of growing a tomato plant for example, where you have to make sure it's nice and warm, and keep aphids off it.  It only works when applied to a noun, for this reason.

Comment: "I've been cultivating to increase my knowledge for several years" is it wrong?

Comment: No, because as I said, you need to cultivate a specific **thing**.